# Fetching data from database through select option tag such that when select 'all' database should select ' * '

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to make a search box using select option tag such that if I select 'all' in select option tag then each data of that column should be fetched.

Given below is my `php` code. Thanks

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $area = $_POST['city'];
    if(isset($_POST['work']!== 'all')) 
        {$work = $_POST['work']; } 
    else {$work = '*';} ;

    $sel2 = "SELECT * FROM `userdata` WHERE `area`='".$area."' AND `work`='".$work."'" ;  
  $res2 = mysqli_query($con,$sel2);
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? What does the query look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're would like to fetch any and all work related data when `work` is equal to `all`, you don't have to mention that explicitly in the SQL query. Mention *that* only when you want to fetch specific work related data. So your code should be like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $area = $_POST['city']; 
    $sel2 = "SELECT * FROM `userdata` WHERE `area`='".$area."'";
    if(isset($_POST['work']) && $_POST['work'] !== 'all') 
        $sel2 .= " AND `work`='".$_POST['work']."'";
    $res2 = mysqli_query($con,$sel2);
```

---

**Sidenote:** Learn about [**prepared statement**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) because right now your query is susceptible to SQL injection attack. Also see [**how you can prevent SQL injection in PHP**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Answer (score 0):

Set up the variables like this

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $area = $_POST['city'];
    if(isset($_POST['work']!== 'all'))
$data=addslashes($_POST['work']); 
        {$work = "AND `work`='".$data."'";
} 
    else {$work = "";
}
///your query should be like this
$sel2 = "SELECT * FROM `userdata` WHERE `area`='".$area."' ".$work."";  
//////so if work is not specified then you don't need to select column WORK in the query. So it works as select * from userdata where area='".$area."';";

  $res2 = mysqli_query($con,$sel2);
```